# Problem with allocating memory in function

Tags: c++

I am not a beginner in C/C++ but I can't seem to find what is wrong with this piece of c++ code. I also tried it with the c equivalent(malloc) and I get the same result.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int *n) {
  n = new int;
  *n = 11;
}

int main() {
  int *num = NULL;
  foo(num);
  std::cout << num << '\n';
  if (num) {
    delete num;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `num` is passed by value. Why would you expect it to change in main?

Comment: If you do not know what is wrong how would we know? I do not see anything wrong., except memory leak you have in `foo()`

Comment: I don't pass the value, I pass the reference. If i passe the value it would be foo(*num), right?

Comment: @DImiTrisXam, you pass the pointer by value. There is no reference in your code.

Comment: Make an alias for `int *` lets say `intptr` and rewrite your code using it. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: You are passing the pointer in as "n", then reassigning only that pointer parameter, it does not change "num" in main().

Comment: @DImiTrisXam: The thing is, your function's definition requires that a pointer be passed as argument to it, not a reference to pointer. You need to change its signature to: `void foo(int* &n) { ... }`

Comment: @machine_1 or for C that would be pointer to pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n` is a pointer that is being passed **by value**, so any modifications made by the function to the pointer itself are not applied to the caller's variable.  And as such, you are leaking memory since you are `new`'ing memory that you are not able to `delete` afterwards.

To do what you are attempting, you need to pass `n` **by reference** instead:

```cpp
void foo(int* &n) {
  n = new int;
  *n = 11;

  // or simply:
  // n = new int(11);
}
```

Otherwise, you should change your function to `return` the new pointer instead of outputting it via a reference parameter:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int* foo() {
  int *n = new int;
  *n = 11;
  return n;

  // or simply:
  // return new int(11);
}

int main() {
  int *num = foo();
  std::cout << num << '\n';
  delete num;
  return 0;
}
```

That being said, in C++11 and later, you should be using `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> &n) {
  n.reset(new int(11));

  // or:
  // std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(11)).swap(n);

  // or, in C++14 and later:
  // n = std::make_unique<int>(11);
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int> num;
  foo(num);
  std::cout << num.get() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> foo() {
  return std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(11));

  // or, in C++14 and later...
  // return std::make_unique<int>(11);
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int> num = foo();
  std::cout << num.get() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```